# How to filter empty line with a 'cut' command?

Tags: cut

I have a tab delimited file with a few fields:

```
f1    f2   f3 
a     b    c
a     c     
d     e    
f     g    a
```

I want to extract the 3rd column with a 'cut'command:

```
cut -f3 t
```

This works. However, how can I filter the empty line in the output? As it can be seen, the 2nd and 3rd lines are empty after they are extracted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To remove empty output:

```
$ cut -f3 file | grep .
f3
c
a
```

Or:

```
$ awk -F'\t' '$3 {print $3}' file
f3
c
a
```

To replace the missing output with a filler:

```
$ awk -F'\t' '{if ($3) print $3; else print "FILL"}' file
f3
c
FILL
FILL
a
```

Or, for people who like the more compact ternary statement:

```
$ awk -F'\t' '{print ($3?$3:"FILL")}' file
f3
c
FILL
FILL
a
```

#### Example with multiple words in field 3

```
$ cat file2
f1      f2      f3
f       g       a b c d
$ cut -f3 file2 | grep .
f3
a b c d
$ awk -F'\t' '$3 {print $3}' file2
f3
a b c d
```

Comment: "cut -f3 file | grep ." doesn't work. The "a" or "c" can be sentence or any length of strings.

Comment: @martin Please try it.  It works for me.  See updated answer for examples.  If it doesn't work for you, please document exactly how your results differ from mine.